# Animation Toggle with Jquery only working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to repeat a CSS animation via the Jquery toggle class method. Right now this is working perfectly in Firefox but not Chrome, Safari, or IOS.

Anyone have thoughts? I'm new to CSS animations so I suspect the problem may be in my animations themselves.

Here's the sketch I'm working on. http://ryanabraham.net/blocks/

thanks in advance!
-ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [vendor prefixed](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) and they will work:

```
div#blocksIn {

    -webkit-animation: bounceInDown 2s;
    animation: bounceInDown 2s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Chrome needs the vendor prefix.